# Silverlight in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

If I need to build a silverlight application and have it work under my asp.net application!

Does that mean I have to create two different vs projects?

One for silverlight the other my asp.net application? Or I can have one in 1? What do I do?

Sorry if this is a silly question..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a separate project for the Silverlight app. At least in VS2010, you can go to ASP.NET's project's properties, Silverlight Applications tab, and select "Add..." to add a Silverlight project with all the plumbing hooked up.

Comment: So I create asp.net app first then I open it and add the silverlight app to the solution tree? Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: No go to your web app's properties, and then the Silverlight Application tab

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a separate project for the Silverlight code. But, you will be able to incorporate that application into an existing ASP.Net project. You will want them both in the same solution, of course.

In the project properties of the Silverlight project there is an option to choose the ASP.Net project to incorporate the Silverlight app into. That's why you want them in the same solution.

Comment: How do I do it extactly? I have my asp.net solution open now how do I add the silverlight solution to it so it becomes 1 solution? Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned by Matt, you would use the project properties of the ASP.Net project to point to the Silverlight project in the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

the silverlight app is technically a class library project. So a separate project would be required.

Comment: Well the Silverlight app uses its own CLR and BCL, so it really has to be a different project.